# Get around same-origin policy to get top URL of a page from inside a cross-domain iframe

Tags: javascript, security, iframe, cross-domain, phantomjs

I've got some code running in an iframe on 3rd-party sites. Some will be directly in the top page, some will be inside another iframe and some of these may be cross-domain. I need to find a way to get the URL value of the top page using any means necessary.

The furthest I can go up due to cross-domain policy is until the browser stops what the code is doing. I catch the error and look at the referrer of the current window context I'm in. Most cases the page above this is the top page, but not necessarily.

The only way I can see around this is building up a list of URLs which I think are the top page, and then sending a bot with a JS browser validate by seeing if the iframe my code got up to was in fact directly nested in them.

That's still not particularly accurate though, and I'm sure there must be another way of doing it...

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely not possible without communicating with some sort of external system. The cleanest/most accurate way to gather data is to get the top window URL if the browser lets you, but catch errors and use the referer with a flag to note it's the referer.

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a way to get the domain in both Chrome and Opera, (in multiple nested cross-domain iframes), though it is not possible in other browsers.

You need to use the 'window.location.ancestorOrigins' property.

I have created a snippet of code below, which should work for you and if you think you can improve the code or comments, please don't hesitate to edit the gist on Github so we can make it even better:

Gist: https://gist.github.com/ocundale/281f98a36a05c183ff3f.js

Code (ES2015):

```
// return topmost browser window of current window & boolean to say if cross-domain exception occurred
const getClosestTop = () => {
    let oFrame  = window,
        bException = false;

    try {
        while (oFrame.parent.document !== oFrame.document) {
            if (oFrame.parent.document) {
                oFrame = oFrame.parent;
            } else {
                //chrome/ff set exception here
                bException = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch(e){
        // Safari needs try/catch so sets exception here
        bException = true;
    }

    return {
        'topFrame': oFrame,
        'err': bException
    };
};

// get best page URL using info from getClosestTop
const getBestPageUrl = ({err:crossDomainError, topFrame}) => {
    let sBestPageUrl = '';

    if (!crossDomainError) {
        // easy case- we can get top frame location
        sBestPageUrl = topFrame.location.href;
    } else {
        try {
            try {
                // If friendly iframe
                sBestPageUrl = window.top.location.href;
            } catch (e) {
                //If chrome use ancestor origin array
                let aOrigins = window.location.ancestorOrigins;
                //Get last origin which is top-domain (chrome only):
                sBestPageUrl = aOrigins[aOrigins.length - 1];
            }
        } catch (e) {
            sBestPageUrl = topFrame.document.referrer;
        }
    }

    return sBestPageUrl;
};

// To get page URL, simply run following within an iframe on the page:
const TOPFRAMEOBJ = getClosestTop();
const PAGE_URL = getBestPageUrl(TOPFRAMEOBJ);
```

If anybody would like the code in standard ES5, let me know, or simply run it through a converter online.